# Remove Toshiba Laptop HDD/SSD password

Tags: windows, ssd, passwords, samsung-ssd

I own a Toshiba (Dynabook) Portege X30-D-19E Laptop with a built-in SSD which I secured with an HDD/SSD password in the BIOS that I want to remove now.

So there is no BIOS password set, but it says the HDD/SSD user and master passwords are registered.

I recall the user password and can boot into Windows, but I don't remember setting a master password. I can change the user password, but can't remove it because if I leave the new password blank, it says the new password doesn't have enough characters.

I have no idea what the value for the master password is (is it a factory default?!, I read something like that on my google research, but couldn't find a default password that worked).

The SSD is a Samsung MZVLW256HEHP-00000 (950 PRO NVMe M.2 PCIe 256GB) so I tried using Samsung Magician to reset it, but the software says secure erase and PSID revert are not supported.

Any idea how to remove the password?

As I can access and backup the data on the drive, it doesn't matter if the data is lost in the progress of removing the password.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This Samsung SSD is pretty secure and will reject most attempts to
unlock it without the correct password or PSID.

You could ask for help from your nearest Samsung Support center.
If the disk is recent enough to still be under support, they could do
the unlocking for you.

A solution might be to do a low-level erase of the disk, in the hope
that this will also wipe out the lock mechanism.

Samsung Magician is in theory the best tool here, or you could try
third-party tools. Below are a couple of such tools:

- [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
  described in the article
  [Top 2 Ways for Samsung SSD Secure Erase – Unrecoverable](https://www.ubackup.com/articles/samsung-ssd-secure-erase.html)
- [BitRaser Drive Eraser](https://www.bitraser.com/bitraser-drive-eraser.php)
  described in the article
  [How To Wipe NVMe and M.2 Drives?](https://www.bitraser.com/kb/how-to-wipe-nvme-and-m.2-drives.php)

These products might be commercial, or the freeware version might not be
enough for the job, but the trial version might do for this one-time task.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't solved the problem of HDD/SSD user and master passwords, I've got the solution for you.
normally you can define if you want to use a user password without necessarily defining a master password, but if you have defined the latter you have to force the master password to delete the user password.
NB: this solution does not work for the SUPERVISOR password.

1. Remove the back cover of your laptop
2. Disconnect the CMOS battery and the laptop battery.
3. press the power button on your laptop (to clear the circuits).
4. Reconnect the laptop battery or simply plug in the power cord and start your laptop, (a message will warn you of a CMOS battery problem).
5. Turn off your laptop, put everything back as it was before.
6. Turn your computer back on, press F2 (this may vary depending on the model of your laptop) and Tadamm! there is no master and user password.
   **NB: (if your model does not have a removable CMOS battery you will find two copper points near the battery location or not far from the ram bars, try to short-circuit these two points while turning on your laptop.  )**